# APC needs restart to see changes

Tags: apache2, apc

I have Apache2 with APC.

When I change something, I have to restart Apache to see the effect. I know 100% for sure it's because of APC.

What is wrong in my settings? (thanks for the help!)

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled = On
apc.optimization  = 0
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 2.6G
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl  = 720
apc.num_files_hint = 102400
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli = 1
apc.cache_by_default  = 1
apc.max_file_size = 220M
apc.stat = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `apc.stat` set to `0`. This means APC will not check whether the file is modified when it's requested, it will always serve it from cache after the first compilation.

To fix you problem either remove `apc.stat = 0` or change it back to default `apc.stat = 1`

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the use of APC if it's recompiling everytime?

Comment: It's doesn't recompile each time. It checks whether the file has been modified since it was compiled. If it hasn't been modified it serves from cache, if it has been modified it recompiles. Unless you have a slow disk or millions of hits you won't really notice a stat call per file. http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

Comment: Woops, my mistake... here you go :-)